# Get Appdata\local\Google path | C++

Tags: c++, path

I want to get the Path of Appdata\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data folder.
When I try with getenv("LocalAppData\Google"), The function fails and returns null.
Cant find it either on KNOWNFOLDERID nor Casidl so ShGetFolderPath is off..

Any other suggestions?

using MVSC.

Comment: That folder is not a standard shell folder that the Shell API knows about.  Is there any reason why you can't get the _Appdata\Local_ folder using **SHGetKnownFolderPath** and append the rest of the path?

Comment: @rrirower , I did so but when i cout << *pPath (The pointer to the file) , It prints some number, Only when i code : wprintf(L"%s" , pPath); it prints the folder path , So do i have to unicode the pPath than append? Any other suggestions?